# Batch files: Is there a way to set up something like "if my batch file errors at any point goto location

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im working on a dos text based game, using batch files to code it. I have a mass amount of `if input == this goto this` esque things going on. However there is one problem.

most of the inputs its checking for are "try" followed by some word. example

```
if "%try%" == "try light" goto Light
```

i figured out that if after all of your "if" functions you place a "goto start" it works as a sort of fail-safe. however if the person typed in "try" followed by gibberish it crashes. and typing out below all of my if functions "if errorlevel 1 goto error" doesn't appear to make a change.

So what I am getting at is, is there a way to set up a function at the start of the batch file that checks for errors. and if an error occurs it will run "goto %location%"?

if what i said is confusing heres what i have in code right now:

```
set /p try=
if “%try%” == “try womens restroom” goto WRestroom
if “%try%” == “try womens” goto WRestroom
if “%try%” == “try mens restroom” goto MRestroom
if “%try%” == “try mens” goto MRestroom
if “%try%” == “try room 302” goto R302
if “%try%” == “try door 302” goto R302
if “%try%” == “try 302” goto R302
if “%try%” == “try room 301” goto Intro2
if “%try%” == “try 301” goto Intro2
if “%try%” == “try office door” goto Office3
if “%try%” == “try third floor office door” goto Office3
if “%try%” == “try office” goto Office3

goto hallway1error
```

If the input is "try" followed by something else CRASH!

Comment: What input you want to validate? Not-existing label or passing special symbols like `|&<>` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple answer. NO.

But this does your problem, `goto hallway1fuckup`. If none of the preceding statements are true then this will run.

Your quotes look wierd. You are doing this in notepad and not Word, aren't you. Type in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: put `echo CRASHED & exit /b` after the last of your `if`statements.

Parsing user input is an ugly thing. If you succeed in making it idiot-save, you can be sure, someone will invent a better idiot.

Maybe at least some of the following techniques helps you:

```
@echo off

:start
echo(
set /p "inp=What to do? "
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%v in ("%inp%") do call :%%v "%%w" 2>nul || goto :error
echo "%inp%" cannot be parsed.
goto :start

:try  REM verb is TRY
:go   REM verb is GO
echo %1|findstr /i "women" >nul && goto :WRestroom
echo(%1|findstr /i "men" >nul && goto :MRestroom
REM important: first test for "women", then for "men"
echo %1|findstr /i "302" >nul && goto :R302
echo %1|findstr /i "301" >nul && goto :R301
echo %1|findstr /i "office" >nul && goto :Office3
echo %1 is not a valid destination
goto :start

:look
:examine
echo verb is LOOK or EXAMINE
echo rest is %1
goto:start

:error
echo invalid verb. Use "try", "go", "look", "examine"
goto :start


 :WRestroom
 :MRestroom
 :R302
 :R301
:office3
echo you entered%0 %~1
if /i "%0"==":Office3" echo Cheater!!
goto :start
```

This uses some tricks.

Trick 1: Disassemble the input into "FirstWord" and "rest" ("tokens=1,*"). Then call "FirstWord" with "rest" as parameter. Discard any errormessages ("2>nul") and if it fails (because label not existent) ("||") goto error

Trick 2: using more than one label to do the same thing ("try" and "go") (the "WRestroom", "MRestroom", "R302", ... is for demo to keep the code short - of course these should be "subroutines" on their own)

Trick 3: scanning for keywords instead of the whole string (just "301" instead of "room 301" or "door 301" or "301")

Trick 4: "&&" works as "if previous command was successful then" (here: "if the keyword was found then")

This is not bulletproof, but you need some knowledge (or bad luck) to let it fail.

Note: you can jump to any label when you enter just the labelname without a verb (for example input "office3" only). Good for cheating - i mean testing.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the error that was occurring was because google docs has weird quotes. lucky me i could "find and replace" all of googles quotes with quotes copied from notepad and it works just fine. Thanks to everyone for helping me.